# Why doesn't drag drop work in a WPF App when Dragging multiple files from Live Mail 2012?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I've created a barebones wpf app in VS2015 community.

Inside the loaded event of the main window, I've set AllowDrop to true.

When I take a single email message from Live Mail 2012, and drag it over my application the cursor changes.

However, if I take two email messages, and try to drop them on my app, I get a no drop icon.  Dropping them onto a folder in Windows Explorer however makes a copy of the files.

I've successfully done this in an MFC app, but can't get it to work in WPF, running on Windows 10, targeting .NET 4.6

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is looking like a bug in WPF.
The solution I came up with was to replace my drop target with a WinForms drop target which can accept the drop.

```
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"

...

<WindowsFormsHost Margin="10">
    <wf:Button AllowDrop="True" 
        x:Name="btnDropTarget" Text="Drop Files here"></wf:Button>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

After that the drag and drop works when you switch on AllowDrop.

Now I have some winforms restyling work to do.